# Recyclerview with alternate 1 column grid row and 2 columns grid row throughout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Android recyclerview with grid layout manager with alternate even and odd number of grid in a single row!

I want to have alternate 2 and 1 grid(s) per row throughout

Comment: You need to use a GridLayoutManager in your recyclerView. Documentation here : [GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html)

Comment: do you want odd even layout? (i.e __ | | __ | | __ )

Comment: Yes something like that like this picture above

Comment: to anyone down voting this question care to explain the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Add it in your activity

```
GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(mContext, 2);
    manager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            return (position % 3 == 0 ? 2 : 1);
        }
    });
```

Refer this link https://www.slideshare.net/devunwired/mastering-recyclerview-layouts to understand layouts in recycler view

Comment: Thanks let me try it out even though I already have 2 different row types for other purposes

Comment: And also I don't want to have different item layout. It is the same layout only can be single or double items of the same layout in even/odd rows position

Comment: then you just have to choose second option, please check updated answer